# How can I sort data from bottom to top to implement pagination in firebase rtdb with newest first?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, pagination, infinite-scroll

I implement firebase realtime database pagination with the code provided here : https://medium.com/@dpkpradhan649/firebase-realtime-database-pagination-in-recyclerview-c3f9a4a7856f
but the issue here is that data is sorted from the oldest post to the newest post. Is there any way to read it from bottom to top or make new posts above the old one in firebase realtime database array.
NB: I try `linearLayoutManager.reverseLayout = true linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true`
but it's not working in this case

Answer (score 0):

just add the newest post as the last item in the array, and the oldest post as the first item in the array, so you need to reverse the variables in the for loop and add them backwards to the new array